# How compile this code on OSX

Tags: c++, c, g++

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct data {
    int nr;
    char const *value;
} dat[] = {
    {1, "Foo"}, {2, "Bar"}, {3, "Hello"}, {4, "World"}
};

int data_cmp(void const *lhs, void const *rhs) 
{
    struct data const *const l = lhs;
    struct data const *const r = rhs;
    return (l->nr > r->nr) - (l->nr < r->nr);
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct data key = { .nr = 3 };
    struct data const *res = bsearch(&key, dat, sizeof(dat)/sizeof(dat[0]), 
                                    sizeof(dat[0]), data_cmp);
    if (!res) {
        printf("No %d not found\n", key.nr);
    } else {
        printf("No %d: %s\n", res->nr, res->value);
    }
}
```

This version of the C++ does not compile the code:

```
$ g++ -v
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Compiles successfully use this version of g++ and add `-fpermissive` option.

```
g++ --std=c++11 -fpermissive main.cpp &&./a.out
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
```

If I need to compile it in OSX, how can I do it?

Comment: The question is not such clear

Comment: Please add the compilation command and exact error message on osx.

Comment: Perhaps the designated initializer list is causing the failure? `struct data key = { .nr = 3 };` That's not legal c++.

Comment: You're also apparently interested in an old version of OS X. The most recent versions don't come with g++ but instead have clang++...

Comment: @BillLynch: There's still an executable `g++`, but it is really `clang++`.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, don't tag it together except when neccessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the code:

```
int data_cmp(void const *lhs, void const *rhs) 
{
    struct data const *const l = lhs;
    struct data const *const r = rhs;
```

is not valid C++ code.  You can't convert from `const void *` to anything else without an explicit cast.  It is valid C code, but not C++.

Either compile with a C compiler, or fix the code so it is valid C++.

```
int data_cmp(void const *lhs, void const *rhs) 
{
    struct data const *const l = (struct data *)lhs;
    struct data const *const r = (struct data *)rhs;
```

Similarly with the assignment of the result of `bsearch()`.  You can also use a `reinterpret_cast<const struct data *>(lhs)`.  Hence, this compiles OK:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct data {
    int nr;
    char const *value;
} dat[] = {
    {1, "Foo"}, {2, "Bar"}, {3, "Hello"}, {4, "World"}
};

int data_cmp(void const *lhs, void const *rhs) 
{
    struct data const *const l = reinterpret_cast<const struct data *>(lhs);
    struct data const *const r = reinterpret_cast<const struct data *>(rhs);
    return (l->nr > r->nr) - (l->nr < r->nr);
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct data key = { .nr = 3 };
    struct data const *res = reinterpret_cast<struct data *>(bsearch(&key, dat, sizeof(dat)/sizeof(dat[0]), 
                                    sizeof(dat[0]), data_cmp));
    if (!res) {
        printf("No %d not found\n", key.nr);
    } else {
        printf("No %d: %s\n", res->nr, res->value);
    }
}
```

However, if you turn on enough warnings, you also end up being told that `.nr` notation is a C99 designated initializer that is not valid in C++ (and that you didn't specify an initializer for the `.value` element).

It's best to compile C code as C code and not as C++ code.

Checked with home-built GCC 5.1.0 and with `clang++` from XCode 6.4 on Mac OS X 10.4.4 Yosemite.